# Computational complexity of the word & conjugacy problems for a (classical) reversible circuit

Tags: group-theory, logic, permutations, computational-complexity, computational-algebra

By *word problem* I mean the decision problem of whether a given reversible circuit is functionally equivalent to the empty one.  It is in co-NP.  The broader *conjugacy problem* asks whether, given $f$ and $g$, there exists a circuit $h$ such that $f=h^{-1} g h$.  I prefer the [right action](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Switching_between_the_left_and_right_action_conventions) definition of conjugation when working with circuits.

For these problems, **does the computational complexity depend more on the circuit width $n$, or on the circuit depth $d$ and the size of the gate alphabet?**  After all, an algorithm polynomial in the order of a permutation group on $2^n$ elements is not practical.

But building a circuit from some subset of the universal classical (i.e., non-quantum) gates, as is typical, greatly restricts the permutations accessible.  Suppose we restrict further, to gates whose number of inputs bounded by some constant $k$--does that help?  For example, 'NCT'--the set of  NOT, CNOT, and Toffoli gates--has $k=3$.  Further still: only the conservative SWAP and Fredkin gates?

For my part, I find the word problem stubbornly resistant to being proved co-NP complete.

---

### **27/9/2021**

I'm looking now at 'T', the Toffoli-only circuits.  Let $\mathbf{T}_n$ designate the group generated by all Toffolis on $n$ circuit lines, and $\mathbf{E}_n$ be the group generated by only SWAPs--called 'exchangers' by (1), and isomorphic to $\mathbf{S}_n$.  $\mathbf{T}_n$ and $\mathbf{E}_n$ are disjoint save for the identity.

**Conjecture:** If, for any word $t \in \mathbf{T}_n$, it is possible to calculate the centralizer $C_{\mathbf{E}_n}(t)$ efficiently (in polynomial time), then the word problem for $\mathbf{T}_n$ is also in P.

---

## References

1. Vos, A. D., Raa, B., & Storme, L. (2002). [Generating the group of reversible logic gates.](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.7042&rep=rep1&type=pdf) Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General, 35(33), 7063–7078. https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/35/33/307